# How to upload images of 10k movies in one go in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am creating the website which contains 10k movies and it has an attribute called movies_logo which stores the logo of the respected movie .So is there any way so that I can upload all the logo of the respected movies in one go because uploading logo of each movie will take lot of time.This is my models.py.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal

class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    picture_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    picture_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genres = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    ratings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=1)
    picture_logo = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
            return self.picture_title
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't the save location for the images, then upload a single picture and see where it gets stored and with what name. If you don't like the naming, [you can change it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). Once that is figured out, you can simply go to your mysql command-line, and set the image field in the database to the file name and structure you have decided and then upload / move the images to the correct location. If you want, you can use a `for` loop to set the image field instead of writing SQL.

Comment: I am using CharField instead of ImageField so that I can pass the path of the Pictureimage ..but I have 10k movies for which I need to pass the images .Can you suggest me how to pass the path for those 10k movies with one go ?

Comment: You have a pattern right? So just go to `manage.py shell` and run a `for` loop to set the objects's `CharField` according to the pattern?

Comment: I will do it ..In between can you clear this please ?       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876166/how-to-integrate-recommender-systempython-file-to-the-django-project

Comment: We tried to extract the 10k images from omdi but around 1k images are missing so if i write a for loop then the movies with no images will display nothing..so is it possible to write try and except statement in manage.py shell so that i can display default image for the movies which don't have image ?

Comment: Instead of giving a default in the database, why don't you give a default where the image is supposed to be rendered (view / template)? That way you won't have to make DB changes when you decide to change the image. Plus, less redundancy.

Comment: In 9k images we have only 6k images ..so adding default for the rest of the 3k images one by one is a huge task and we dont have images continuously .

Comment: Ok, in any case, you should always be able to use a `try-catch` statement and catch for `DoesNotExist` or the appropriate error class.